# Can't see my files with "ls" anymore

Tags: command-line, mv

### HELP! I think I broke my DESKTOP :/

I was playing around with the Terminal and trying to practice moving, renaming, and copying files when I think I screwed something up.

I was attempting to move multiple .txt files using the *wildcard but it wasn't working, so I began to play around with it and I did something wrong.

I am no longer able to list the content of the home directory using `ls` command

Here is a list of a few of the commands.

```
212  mv Desktop/*.txt Desktop/texts/*.txt
213  ls Desktop
214  mv Desktop *.txt
215  Desktop/texts
216  mv Desktop *.txt Desktop/texts
217  mv Desktop *.txt Desktop/texts/
218  mv Desktop *.txt ~/Desktop/texts/
219  mv Desktop *.txt ~/Desktop/texts
220  mv Desktop *.txt ~/Desktop/
```

---

Here is Outputfrom Command `find ~ -not -path '*/\.*' -type f -name '*'`

```
/home/dlundy1/Desktop/examples.desktop
/home/dlundy1/*.txt/test5
/home/dlundy1/*.txt/texts/task
/home/dlundy1/*.txt/texts/tasks
/home/dlundy1/*.txt/texts/tasks~
/home/dlundy1/*.txt/test2
/home/dlundy1/*.txt/test6
/home/dlundy1/*.txt/test1
/home/dlundy1/*.txt/test4
/home/dlundy1/*.txt/test3
/home/dlundy1/*.txt/test
/home/dlundy1/Pictures/my pics/me
/home/dlundy1/Pictures/temp/Flyer.jpg
/home/dlundy1/Pictures/Screenshots/s.png
/home/dlundy1/Pictures/Screenshots/Selection_001.png
/home/dlundy1/Pictures/Selection_001.png
dlundy1@dlundy1-HP-Pavilion-g7-Notebook-PC:/$ ^C
dlundy1@dlundy1-HP-Pavilion-g7-Notebook-PC:/$
```

---

Here is Output from command `ls -l ~`

```
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 3 dlundy1 dlundy1 4096 Apr 16 14:59 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x 2 dlundy1 dlundy1 4096 Apr 15 22:06 Documents
drwxr-xr-x 3 dlundy1 dlundy1 4096 Apr 16 00:30 Downloads
drwxr-xr-x 2 dlundy1 dlundy1 4096 Apr 15 22:06 Music
drwxr-xr-x 5 dlundy1 dlundy1 4096 Apr 16 11:54 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x 2 dlundy1 dlundy1 4096 Apr 15 22:06 Public
drwxr-xr-x 2 dlundy1 dlundy1 4096 Apr 15 22:06 Templates
drwxr-xr-x 2 dlundy1 dlundy1 4096 Apr 15 22:06 Videos
```

Comment: Please post the output of `find ~ -not -path '*/\.*' -type f -name '*'`. **Please copy and paste, don't type**

Comment: It seems You've been trying to move Desktop and those files...

Comment: @dlundy1 "I am no longer able to list the content of the home directory using `ls` command" What happens when you try to do that? Is nothing displayed, or is there some error message, or something else altogether? Also, the output you've given isn't really readable in a comment, and some information might even be lost. Instead, please [edit] your question to provide it (and any other additional info you have). To make text from the Terminal appear correctly in your question, paste it in, select it, and press Ctrl+K (or click the `{}` tool in the editing toolbar). This formats it as code.

Comment: ** Eliah** Yes, nothing is displayed.

Comment: In case you haven't already figured it out `mv Desktop/*.txt Desktop/texts/*.txt` doesn't do the kind of cool pattern-matching think you were probably hoping it would.  `mv Desktop/*.txt Desktop/texts/` will move all the .txt's to the 'texts' subdir, but your command won't. Not exactly sure what; might move all of them to single file called `\*.txt`, possibly deleting most of them, or more likely fail unless there's exactly one .txt in the source dir. In any case, you're not doin it rite.

Comment: You *said* nothing is displayed but then you show the output where things clearly *are* displayed...

Comment: psusi, you came to the discussion late. The original post was updated several times to present new info. So that is why output was later displayed. understand?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## What happened?

You've renamed the `Desktop` directory to `*.txt` by using the `mv` command. Unfortunately, the asterisk on the file name will probably be interpreted as a [glob pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)), keeping you from repairing the mistake.

---

## Reverting the operation

#### From the graphical interface

1. Open the File Manager.
2. Go to you home folder.
3. Locate a folder called `*.txt`.
4. Rename it to `Desktop`

#### From the command line

Running `mv "/home/dlundy1/*.txt" /home/dlundy1/Desktop` will be enough, as any argument wrapped by simple or double quotes won't be interpreted as glob.

Comment: Wow, such a simple solution. Thanks, It worked!

Comment: @dlundy1 if it worked, please click the tick next to it to mark it as accepted.